android widget remote view service onCreate is called after app is destroyed
I have a widget for my app which uses a grid view to display a number of items. Each time I enter the home screen I call backend endpoint to get latest data and I update widget using below code
public static void updateWidgets(Context context, Class<? extends AppWidgetProvider> providerClass) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, providerClass);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, providerClass));
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

And in my RemoteViewService, I bind data to each view.
Problem is, when I enter application and after I get backend response,  updateWidgets method is called, I remove application from background, and as soon as app removed from background, I see widget displaying empty data.
In logs I noticed below pattern, which shows that remote view service is created after app is destroyed


Your RemoteViewsService can be called at any point in time, and it needs to be able to respond.

thanks, updated code and it worked @CommonsWare
